# Fluid simulation doesn't fall

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am beginning to simulate fluids in blender and doing my first one I see that water stays in the middle of the simulation and does not fall. Someone knows why this might happen? Thank you[image]

Comment: Have you accidentally disabled gravity?

Comment: please provide your blend file. often the resolution is too low. just increase it and bake again.

Comment: Firstly, where is the inflow? Maybe you changed something and it didn't bake it. Go to the cache and bake a few frames and see if it falls.